# Not able to edit color attribute magento 2.0.0

Tags: magento2, attributes

when I try to save color attribute error display 
Error :**Admin is a required field in the each row**

http://awesomescreenshot.com/05e65t0g1c

all other attribute working fine but the only issue with a color attribute.
I am using `Magento 2.0.0`

Comment: Add your solutions as answer below so another users have helpful in future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set "max_input_vars" to 300000 or more into your php.ini file.

Thanks